# Cognos - Conditionally hide a column, and summarise the remaining columns

Tags: conditional-statements, cognos

I have a report with a static choice on the prompt page. The user can choose 'Full Detail', or 'Summarised'.

For a simplified example, say my report has these columns: Customer, Product, Date, Quantity, Value.

I would like to be able to show/hide the Date column based on the detail level choice, and have the Quantity and Value columns aggregate into a single Customer/Product line. I know how to show/hide the column (tying the choice variable to the column's Render Variable), but this does not do the aggregation, only makes the column invisible.

I have thought about doing a separate report page for Full Detail and Summary, but in my actual report I have a second choice box with which the user can choose a field to summarise by (e.g. Customer or Product), and the report will section-group by that field. At the moment I am doing that one per page (5 of them). Doing the detail choice the same way would mean I would need 10 pages. There is surely a better way.

Full detail:

```
Customer     Product     Date          Qty       Value
ABCD         Things      22/10/2014    10        1.00
                         21/10/2014    40        4.00
                         23/10/2014    50        5.00
```

Summarised (How it looks at the moment, after hiding the Date column):

```
Customer     Product   Qty       Value
ABCD         Things    10        1.00
                       40        4.00
                       50        5.00
```

Summarised (How I would like it to look):

```
Customer     Product   Qty       Value
ABCD         Things    100       10.00
```

I am using Cognos Report Studio 10.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not just hide column.
You should also set same value for this column in all rows
Instead of just [Date] in this column set

```
    if (?HideDate? = 1) then ('') else ([Date])
```

or, if you prefer CASE

```
    case ?HideDate? when 1 then '' else [Date] end
```

replace ?HideDate? = 1 with you own condition

Comment: Combined with making your Qty and Value columns Totals, and this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey's answer is great if you are using the standard Cognos 'auto-group and summarize' functionality.

If you have a custom aggregate that includes the [Date] column in its definition, you might squeeze a bit of performance gain out of modifying the aggregate function itself to disregard the [Date] column when a summarized total is desired.

If your aggregate function was:

```
total([Value] for [Customer],[Product],[Date])
```

..you might change this to a CASE statement like so:

```
CASE ?HideDate?
WHEN 1 then total([Value] for [Customer],[Product]) 
ELSE total([Value] for [Customer],[Product],[Date]) 
END
```

The data items after a 'for' clause usually end up in a GROUP BY clause in the resultant SQL. Limiting the items grouped, when possible, can help performance. In this case the performance improvement would likely be slight since there will only be one distinct value in Alexey's solution, but it's something to consider.